# Oracle Network Encryption from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, amazon-rds, oracle-sql-developer, encryption

I'm configuring [Oracle Network Encryption](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/asoconfg.htm#DBSEG9599) on my Amazon RDS Oracle SE2 12.1 instance per [these instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.Options.NetworkEncryption.html). I've got the RDS instance configured with the appropriate option group, enabling network encryption on the server using the `NATIVE_NETWORK_ENCRYPTION` option. How do I configure my *SQL Developer* client to require encrypted connections to the server?

The Oracle and Amazon docs mention updating the connection properties and/or sqlnet.ora, but I'm not sure where to do that for SQL Developer. Is it possible to configure the various `SQLNET.*_CLIENT` encryption settings directly in the connection string (jdbc url)? If not, can these properties be specified directly in the SQL Developer Connection properties somewhere, or is some external configuration needed?

Comment: Instead of JDBC, just use the OCI/Thick driver with an sqlnet.ora. To secure JDBC connections , you would have to set `CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CHECKSUM_LEVEL, "REQUESTED"` in a `Properties` instance in Java code.

Comment: Thanks. My question is: how/where do I configure the encryption properties/sqlnet.ora in _SQL Developer_ (not in Java code)?

Comment: define TNS_ADMIN : directory where you want sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora
create your sqlnet.ora